# Google Maps V3 Street View Service and getPanoramaByLocation() effect on quota?

Tags: google-maps

In my app I need to check the existance of a street view in a given area `LatLng` using **Street View Service** and `getPanoramaByLocation()` .

Does this consume my request quota? If so in what way? I did not find a simple answer to this in the documentation.

Comment: This is not really a programming question.  The Google Maps API forum is suitable for asking a general question about the API: https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/

Comment: I'll try the forum then. Thanks!